# Return String After Character in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-shared-libraries

I'm using shared libraries in groovy.
I have this variable which will return : **feature/nameofthebranch**

```
def BRANCH = steps.sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD').trim()
```

However I only need the character after the "/"
I've tried split and other stuff but doesn't work as I would like to, maybe because I'm clumsy at groovy.

Expected result should be from **feature/nameofthebranch** to **"nameofthebranch"**

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
def BRANCH = steps.sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD').trim()

echo "${BRANCH.split('/')[1]}"
```